# How to use Sqlite column string values as input to Python array?

Tags: python, arrays, sqlite, select

I have a Sqlite table with the following columns

```
DATE           SYMBOL          NAME
timestamp1      XYZ             ABC
timestamp2      YYZ             XBC
...
```

I have a longer program, which takes input values in a Python Array like this;

```
mynames = ['ABC', 'BBC', ...]
```

My question is how to take the column values `ABC`, `XBC` and so on and use it as input to the aforementioned array. Here's what I have right now;

```
def get_Data():
    # from math import *
    data = cursor.execute(''' SELECT * FROM databaseName ORDER BY NAME''')
    for record in data:
        print ('Timestamp: '+str(record[0]))
        print ('Symbol: '+str(record[1]))
        print ('Name: '+str(record[2]))+'\n')
```

Please note I need the quotes added around the column values. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `SELECT NAME FROM databaseName ORDER BY NAME` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but how do I make those values input to my array with the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with this. However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way.

```
mynames = []

def read_Data():
    # from math import *
    data = cursor.execute(''' SELECT NAME FROM databaseName WHERE ... ORDER BY ...''')
    for record in data:
        #print ("'"+str(record[0])+"'"+'\n')
        mynames.append("'"+str(record[0])+"'")
```